# Editing bot for Line

Tags: python, github, termux

I got bot script from https://github.com/merkremont/LineVodka

and I want to add this script but it say syntax error / unexpected indent

```
elif msg.text in ["Tag all","Tagall"]:
    if msg.from_ in admin:
        group = client.getGroup(msg.to)
        nama = [contact.mid for contact in group.members]

        cb = ""
        cb2 = ""
        strt = int(0)
        akh = int(0)
        for md in nama:
           akh = akh + int(6)

           cb += """{"S":"""+json.dumps(str(strt))+""","E":"""+json.dumps(str(akh))+""","M":"""+json.dumps(md)+"},"""

           strt = strt + int(7)
           akh = akh + 1
           cb2 += "@nrik \n"

        cb = (cb[:int(len(cb)-1)])
        msg.contentType = 0
        msg.text = cb2
        msg.contentMetadata ={'MENTION':'{"MENTIONEES":['+cb+']}','EMTVER':'4'}

        try:
           sendMessage(msg)
        except Exception as error:
           print error
```

Comment: try checking the tabbing format. It might be using spaces instead of tabs and that has to be consistent with your code.

Comment: i was checked all line using spaces, and found 2 line not using 4 spaces. i was changed it but still syntax error

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be in this line

```
cb += """{"S":"""+json.dumps(str(strt))+""","E":"""+json.dumps(str(akh))+""","M":"""+json.dumps(md)+"},"""
```

where you input the string as single double quote ("), but close it with triple (""").

Try

```
cb += """{"S":"""+json.dumps(str(strt))+""","E":"""+json.dumps(str(akh))+""","M":"""+json.dumps(md)+"},"
```

**edit:**
Sorry, reading the question one more time I realized that that's not the problem. Nonetheless I was expecting an error for that. Anyway... Check again if your indentation is consistent with the script, especially if your elif lines with the other if and else statements.

Comment: elif msg.text in ["Tag all","Tagall"] ^ syntax error: invalid syntax